# Is javaFX supported by Corretto?

Tags: javafx, corretto

Is it planned to have support of javaFX in Corretto distributions ?
OpenJDK-8 distributions do not have JavaFX support, I am wondering if Corretto will support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Corretto includes OpenJFX.

Answer (score 5):

Some of JavaFX is supported, however the web browser is not, so it depends upon what you use.

[Is JavaFX media supported by Corretto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876524/is-javafx-media-supported-by-corretto)