# Is JavaFX media supported by Corretto?

Tags: javafx, java-8, corretto

"I am getting the following exception when running my JavaFX 8 application under Corretto.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: `C:\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\bin\glib-lite.dll`

My application works fine under Oracle JDK 1.8.

I confirmed the missing dll does not exist anywhere in the Corretto folder. The following which I found to be in OpenJFX and also present in Azul's ZuluFX are not in the Corretto runtime:

- `gstreamer-lite.dll`
- `glib-lite.dll`
- `fxplugins.dll`
- `jfxmedia.dll`
- `jfxwebkit.dll`
- `prism_es2.dll`
- `ucrtbase.dll`

Will this be addressed in an update? Or perhaps Corretto is intentionally choosing to not fully support some JavaFX media capabilites?"

Comment: This is an open issue in Corretto : https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/26

Comment: Thanks TornadoFX Fan!

Answer (score 5):

As of today (2020-01-23) Corretto for Java 8 includes Java FX 8 so the compilation is fine but you may encounter problems at runtime. In my case I found out that jfxwebkit.dll was missing so I could not display HTML panels in JavaFX.

So I ended up using Azul Zulu which includes a full version of Java FX 8. BEWARE: make sure to download the "JDK FX" edition of Zulu which is not the default one on the download page. So far so good.

Answer (score 4):

As of today, Corretto doesn't include JavaFX media. It has been requested in https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/26 and the team is working on the best way to include it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

We are using https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-8-lts as an alternative to Oracle, since it includes all of JavaFX including webkit.  One of our projects using webkit is http://github.com/cirdles/squid - load the example project and then open the expression manager and webkit is used to render expressions using MathML.