# Does Amazon Corretto JRE supports any JavaFx dependency?

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8, java-11, corretto

I need to add javafx dependency(as we do for other dependencies, adding in the pom) to my project which runs on amazon corretto jre, so here I have two questions:-

1. Is there any javafx dependency that would work with Amazon Corretto jre?
2. If so, could anyone please suggest what version of amazon corretto jre supports what version of javafx
   dependency?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876524/is-javafx-media-supported-by-corretto

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaFX media supported by Corretto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876524/is-javafx-media-supported-by-corretto)